# twitter typeahead dropbown suggestion not working

Tags: twitter, drop-down-menu, typeahead.js, search-suggestion

I am using twitter typeahead for auto completing and its a great plug-in for auto-completion. However I had one issue using it.

It doesn't show the top suggestions at the beginning of a drop down as shown in image attached
[image]

Here the word started with magic, but the suggestion dropdown is showing "Altered Art Magic singles" as first suggestion. I know it has the word magic in it, but shouldn't it be listed at the last of suggestion as there are other words that started with "Magic"

How do I make the drop down to show those suggestions first, that begin with the letter typed and rest at the bottom.

In case of the image, I want to show "Altered Art Magic Singles" at the bottom of drop down list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will show them in the order received from the server (assuming you're using `remote:` or `prefetch:`). Just sort them on the server. (Or if using `local`, sort them locally :)